# Appcelerator: Variable scope issue

Tags: javascript, appcelerator-mobile

I am using the following code in Titanium Appcelerator to connect with remote Host:

```
var connect_remote = function(url)
{
    /*
     * make sure that the Device is connected before initiate process as we don't want to force
     * the user to open remote stream just for sake of new entries
     */
     //alert("In Func" + is_connected());
     var d_data = null;
     if(is_connected())
     {

         var c = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
         var data = null;
         c.setTimeout(10000);
         c.onload = function()
            {
                if (c.status == 200 )
                {
                    data = this.responseData;
                    Titanium.App.Properties.setString('returnData',data);
                }
            };

        c.error = function(e)
        {
            alert("Error = "+e.error);
        }
        c.open('GET',url);
        c.send();
     }
}
```

I want to return the value of **data** variable which is supposed to keep the value of the response, so that I could use but it is always returning null or undefined. How do I return the value **data** from it?

Comment: You should clarify what you mean by "return the value of **data**". That's a confusing statement given the fact that in JavaScript the `return` statement is important.  If you simply mean that you want to **use** the value, and that the Titanium call you make to "setString()" is the only problem, well, you should clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you mean, but I *think* you want your "connect_remote()" function to return some value to you. You can't do that in an asynchronous environment like yours.  Instead, you can pass a function in to "connect_remote()" that can be passed the "data" value when the "onload" handler runs.

```
var connect_remote = function(url, handler)
{
    /*
     * make sure that the Device is connected before initiate process as we don't want to force
     * the user to open remote stream just for sake of new entries
     */
     //alert("In Func" + is_connected());
     var d_data = null;
     if(is_connected())
     {

         var c = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
         var data = null;
         c.setTimeout(10000);
         c.onload = function()
            {
                if (c.status == 200 )
                {
                    data = this.responseData;
                    Titanium.App.Properties.setString('returnData',data);
                    handler(data);
                }
            };

        c.error = function(e)
        {
            alert("Error = "+e.error);
        }
            c.open('GET',url);
        c.send();
     }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear which function do I need to return value of response Data; either handler or connect_remote or I store value in some global var?

Comment: OK let me put it this way: if you want a `return` statement somewhere, like `return data;` in the "onload" function, well, you can't do that - the "onload" function is invoked *asynchronously*, so there's no place for it to return a value - there's nothing to "catch" the return value, in other words. But you can pass through a function as in my example.

Comment: I can understand that due to async nature it's not possible to predict when value arrives hence can't get value even executing 'connect_remote' function. The handler value does fetch the value but the entire solution would not be so generic as I want to make "url" dynamic and fetch desired data and for every HTTP request I would have to repeat entire logic

Answer (score 0):

Try "data = c.responseData" instead of "data = this.responseData". Just a wild guess based on [this](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/83851/xhr-null-response)...